# Creating shared directory between containers with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis

My Flask app (webapp) has two directories inside (uploads and images). I want my second container (rq-worker) to have access to them, so it can take something from uploads, and save back to images. How I can organize this inside my docker-compose.yml?

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  web:
    build: ./webapp
    image: webapp
    container_name: webapp
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
      - mongodb

  redis-server:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis-server
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2-bionic
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  rq-worker:
    image: jaredv/rq-docker:0.0.2
    container_name: rq-worker
    command: rq worker -u redis://redis-server:6379 high normal low
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    depends_on:
      - redis-server

  dashboard:
    build: ./dashboard
    image: dashboard
    container_name: dashboard
    ports:
      - "9181:9181"
    command: rq-dashboard -H redis-server
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify a volume like this:

```
volumes:
  data-volume:
```

And then attach it to your services, e.g. for `web`:

```
  web:
    build: ./webapp
    image: webapp
    container_name: webapp
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/my/mnt/point
```

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) has more info, also how to configure a volume driver, e.g. if you want to have a volume on NFS. Furthermore [this lists available](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#volume-plugins) volume plugins which enable Docker volumes to persist across multiple Docker hosts.

Comment: So now I have to change paths inside my view to point to  ie: /var/lib/uploads when saving and not inside my webapp/uploads ?

Comment: Your exact setup is not obvious from the `docker-compose.yml` but in general you can mount your volumes wherever you like in the FS.